# LM338 based psu with arduino based voltmeter

Tags: power-supply

I want to make sure I'm doing this correctly before I put everything together.

I'm using fixed resistors just for testing purposes. I do have a digital pot.
The [LM338](http://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM138.pdf) uses a voltage divider to set the output voltage. I've configured R1 as 240ohms and R2 as 3.3K which gives me 16v. I measured the voltage between adj and output pin which gave me 1.2v. Am guessing that's the voltage coming out of the voltage divider yes? So I just wire this to a ADC pin on my arduino yes?

Comment: Always measure supply voltage against _ground_, nothing else. If you send 16V-something into your MCU, you will most likely fry it.

Answer (score 5):

The LM338 will regulate it's output so that it's 1.2V (the voltage you measured) higher than the adjust input. Ignoring the adjust input current for a moment you get a current of

\$\dfrac{1.24V}{240\Omega} = 5.17mA \$

through the 240\$\Omega\$ resistor. The same current flows through the 3300\$\Omega\$ resistor, so the voltage across it will be

\$ 3300\Omega \cdot 5.17mA = 17.05V \$

Adding the 1.24V reference voltage to that should give you \$18.3V\$ output voltage. You say you have 16V. Is your input voltage high enough? You need a 3V margin, so input should be 21.5V at least.

**edit**
I ignored the adjust pin current because at 45 \$\mu\$A it's so much lower than the 5mA, but let's do the calculation properly:

\$ V_{OUT} = V_{REF} \cdot \left(1 + \dfrac{R2}{R1}\right) + I_{ADJ} \cdot R2 \$
\$ V_{OUT} = 1.24V \cdot \left(1 + \dfrac{3300\Omega}{240\Omega} \right) + 45\mu A \cdot 3300\Omega = 18.44V
 \$

so that agrees with our first calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Summary

- Great care. Read carefully. Tell us more. Your comments imply major misunderstandings.
- To measure Vout you will need to scale Vout down to an ADC safe level.
- Your digital pot may be a digital not if you connect it to ~ 17V.
- 1.2V is not the voltage you want to measure with the ADC.
- The 16V you mention is probably the wrong voltage to meaure.

---

You need to specify WHERE you are measuring the voltages that you mention.
 You probably are not measuring the 16V where Steven assumes you are.

Referring to the diagram below.
 The LM338 outputs a 1.2V reference voltage between Vout and Vadj.
 This appears across R1 as shown below.
 Most of the current in R1 also flows through R2. We ignore the small difference for now.
 As the current in the two resistors is "the same" the voltage in each will be proportional to their resistance values as V =- I x R.
 So if V across R1 = 1.2V the V across R2 = 3300/240 x 1.2 = 16.5V.
 That's the voltage across R2.
 SO the output voltage across Vout = Vr1 + Vr2 = 1.2 + 16.5 = 17.7 Volt.

It seems likely that you are measuring about 16V across R1 rather than Vout across R1 + R2. Yes?

[image]

The LM338 has a "dropout voltage"  - this is the minimum voltage that it needs between Vin and Vout to operate. At about zero load Vdropout is about 2V (data sheet, page 3, bottom. middle) and this rises to about 2.75V at heavy load.

So to get the 17.7V you should be seeing you need at least 17.7 + 2 = 19.7V - say 20V minimum. If you don't have Vin >= about 20V it may not work.

---

Your description of what you want to do is incomplete. You throw in mention of an ADC with no mention of what you are trying to achieve. If you ant to measure output voltage you ned to measure between Vout and ground. If you connect an Arduino ADC input to ~ 17V you will get magic smoke. You will need to scale this voltage down to Arduino ADC suitable voltages with a voltage divider. 2 resistors will probably suffice.

---

Your statement about 1.2v comong out of the voltage divide being 1.2V is incorrect. The output is Vout = *here) 17.&V. If you want 17.7 V this is the correct way to get it. If you want some other voltage this is not the ay to get it :-) - ie R value need changing.

NBNBNBNB - great care - Your digital pot is probably ground referenced and if so will need to connect between ground and Vadj. ie it IS R2 if R1 is a fixed resistor OR it IS all of R1 + R2. Rhe voltage across R2 = Vout -1.2V. The voltage across R1+R2 = Vout. Your digital pot MUST be rated to withstand these voltages. It is quite possible that it isn't.

The MAX5431 [datasheet here](http://datasheets.maxim-ic.com/en/ds/MAX5430-MAX5431.pdf)   digital pot appears at a glance to be the highest voltage rated d pot available from Digikey. It is specd at ~15V max. You may need to add extra circuitry to allow you to use a lower voltage rated digital pot.

http://datasheets.maxim-ic.com/en/ds/MAX5430-MAX5431.pdf